# For what value of $t$ is that ranks of the following matrix $ A$ equal $3$ ?

Tags: linear-algebra

For  what value of $t$ is that ranks of the following matrix $ A$ equal $3$ ?

$A=\begin{vmatrix}t & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1& t & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & t & 1\\ 1& 1 & 1 & t\end{vmatrix}.$

My answer : i take t = 1, then the   rank  of A = 1  so  it  t=1  is not possible, as  i  take  take t=0  then Rank  of A =  4 so it is not possible...

pliz  help me,,,,is  there  any  tricks  to calculate Matrix $Ranks A = 3$

any hints /solution will be aprreciated.

thanks  u

Comment: Write a linear combination of zero by the columns of $A$ and play with them until you "see" something.

Comment: You certainly need the matrix to be singular; its determinant is a polynomial in $t$, so a good start would be to find it, and its roots.

Comment: Do you have the definition of determinants? Hint if so: what does rank<4 imply about determinant of this 4 by 4 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rank is to be less than $4$, then the determinant must be $0$. The determinant can only be $0$ for a very limited number of values of $t$, and you've already found one of them ($t=1$), so $t-1$ divides the determinant. In fact, since $t=1$ gives a rank lower than $3$, $t-1$ divides the determinant several times.

The rest are not very hard to find by direct calculation and polynomial division. Check those and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If you know some spectral graph theory you can see that $t=-3$ gives the Laplacian of $K_4$ and by Kirchofs Theorem the rank is correct.